# Extraer valores numéricos de un txt y convertirlos en listas de enteros

Tags: python, texto

quisiera reformular una pregunta (creo que en este post se entenderá mejor) y que está relacionada con el manejo de archivos de texto, y es la siguiente:

Tengo un archivo de texto (txt) que contiene:

---

Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion:  ['1', '4', '17', '12', '56', '46']

Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion:  ['2', '5', '18', '32', '66', '86']

### Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion:  ['1', '9', '10', '22', '36', '46']

Quisiera extraer de ese archivo txt los números que figuran despues de la palabra "Combinacion", es decir: 1, 4, 17, 12, 56 ,46, 2, 5 ..... y asi sucesivamente hasta el último (46). Quiero almacenarlos en una lista y que sean números enteros (para poder imprimirla y manejarla posteriormente).

Me he quedado atascado en el código ya que solo consigo imprimir los números dígito a dígito, es decir, por ejemplo, en vez del "22" solo consigo imprimir ("2", "2"). ¿Alguien me podria ayudar con ello por favor?. De antemano muchas gracias, pongo mi código bajo estas lineas.

```
                    with open("Bonoloto.txt", "r") as file:
                    #Leer todas las lineas del archivo
                    lines2 = file.readlines()
                    #Recorrer cada linea del archivo
                    vacia2 = list()
                    for line in lines2:
                        for a in line[43:75]:
                             if a.isalnum() == True:
                                  a_1 = int(a)
                                  vacia2.append(a_1)
                    print(vacia2)
```

Comment: ¿Esto es python por lo que veo?

Comment: si, disculpas por no haberlo reseñado

Comment: El error está en `for a in line[43:75]:`. Ahí haces que la variable `a` recorre caracter por caracter.

Answer (score 0):

hice una pequeña demo para enseñar como funciona la entrada de leer él
txt ya la tienes bien, por eso lo omití usando texto el cual mi primer for se corresponde a tu primer for, pero a partir de eso, cambio las cosas.

Primera línea, parte a parte, cojo la parte que nos interesa, la cual es la que está dentro los [], lo busco en vez del índice con el carácter, ya que podría cambiar por un espacio no deseado.etc, después elimino las comas simples, finalmente divido los números por las comas entre sí. Esto nos devuelve un array con los números, pero en formato string y quedaría así el codigo:

```
text= txt[txt.index('[')+1:txt.index(']')].replace("\'","").split(',')#los numeros en un array de string
```

La segunda línea este es un formato reducido de un for por cada índice de l'array lo convertimos en int y lo añadimos a una array que finalmente lo meteremos en una lista.

```
[int(x) for x in text]
```

Es equivalente a:

```
a=[]
for x in text:
    a.append(int(x))
```

Codigo completo:

```
texto=["Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion: ['1', '9', '10', '22', '36', '46']","Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion: ['2', '5', '18', '32', '66', '86']"] #entrada  del libro
vacia2 = [] # salida
for txt in texto:
  text= txt[txt.index('[')+1:txt.index(']')].replace("\'","").split(',')#los numeros en un array de string
  vacia2.append([ int(x) for x in text])#Convertir en int añadir una array con los numeros a vacia2

print(vacia2)
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, me olvidé comentar que en el archivo de texto voy incluyendo lineas semanalmente, por lo tanto, lo que necesitaba es que el script automaticamente extrajese los datos numericos que figuran en el txt y los convirtiese en listas de enteros (pero sin indicarle que datos son, es decir que lea el txt mediante un bucle y devuelva la lista de numeros que figuran en el txt en una lista de enteros), la verdad no se si me he expresado bien, pido disculpas de antemano.